# can material design dataTables columns be styled directly with css custom properties (no framework)

Tags: html, css, material-design

Specifically I would like to be able to 
1) set the width of a dataTable column
2) hide a column

I have a codepen with a functioning data table, but I can't find any reference to the css one may use.

I'm attempting to do this without a framework and without Webpack or alternatives. I.e. just css and not sass.

https://codepen.io/jgbgy/pen/bGdVNzL?editors=1111

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Material Design Data Table</title>

  <!-- material DEsign -->
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="table1" class="mdc-data-table">
    <table class="mdc-data-table__table" aria-label="Dessert calories">
      <thead>
        <tr class="mdc-data-table__header-row">
          <th class="mdc-data-table__header-cell mdc-data-table__header-cell--checkbox" role="columnheader" scope="col">
            <div class="mdc-checkbox mdc-data-table__header-row-checkbox mdc-checkbox--selected">
              <input type="checkbox" class="mdc-checkbox__native-control"
                aria-label="Checkbox for header row selection" />
              <div class="mdc-checkbox__background">
                <svg class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark" viewbox="0 0 24 24">
                  <path class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark-path" fill="none" d="M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59" />
                </svg>
                <div class="mdc-checkbox__mixedmark"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="mdc-data-table__header-cell" role="columnheader" scope="col">data1</th>
          <th class="mdc-data-table__header-cell" role="columnheader" scope="col">data2</th>
          <th class="mdc-data-table__header-cell" role="columnheader" scope="col">data3</th>
          <th class="mdc-data-table__header-cell" role="columnheader" scope="col">data4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="mdc-data-table__content">
        <tr data-row-id="u0" class="mdc-data-table__row">
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell mdc-data-table__cell--checkbox">
            <div class="mdc-checkbox mdc-data-table__row-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" class="mdc-checkbox__native-control" aria-labelledby="u0" />
              <div class="mdc-checkbox__background">
                <svg class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark" viewbox="0 0 24 24">
                  <path class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark-path" fill="none" d="M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59" />
                </svg>
                <div class="mdc-checkbox__mixedmark"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell">r1c1</td>
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell">r1c2</td>
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell">r1c3</td>
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell">r1c4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-row-id="u1" class="mdc-data-table__row mdc-data-table__row--selected" aria-selected="true">
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell mdc-data-table__cell--checkbox">
            <div class="mdc-checkbox mdc-data-table__row-checkbox mdc-checkbox--selected">
              <input type="checkbox" class="mdc-checkbox__native-control" checked aria-labelledby="u1" />
              <div class="mdc-checkbox__background">
                <svg class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark" viewbox="0 0 24 24">
                  <path class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark-path" fill="none" d="M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59" />
                </svg>
                <div class="mdc-checkbox__mixedmark"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell">Offline</td>
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell">monarch: prod shared ares-managed-features-provider-heavy</td>
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell">Huge</td>
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell">Triaged</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-row-id="u2" class="mdc-data-table__row mdc-data-table__row--selected" aria-selected="true">
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell mdc-data-table__cell--checkbox">
            <div class="mdc-checkbox mdc-data-table__row-checkbox mdc-checkbox--selected">
              <input type="checkbox" class="mdc-checkbox__native-control" checked aria-labelledby="u2" />
              <div class="mdc-checkbox__background">
                <svg class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark" viewbox="0 0 24 24">
                  <path class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark-path" fill="none" d="M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59" />
                </svg>
                <div class="mdc-checkbox__mixedmark"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell">Online</td>
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell">monarch: prod shared ares-managed-features-provider-heavy</td>
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell">Minor</td>
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell">Not triaged</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-row-id="u3" class="mdc-data-table__row">
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell mdc-data-table__cell--checkbox">
            <div class="mdc-checkbox mdc-data-table__row-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" class="mdc-checkbox__native-control" aria-labelledby="u3" />
              <div class="mdc-checkbox__background">
                <svg class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark" viewbox="0 0 24 24">
                  <path class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark-path" fill="none" d="M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59" />
                </svg>
                <div class="mdc-checkbox__mixedmark"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell">Online</td>
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell">Arcus watch slowdown</td>
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell">Negligible</td>
          <td class="mdc-data-table__cell">Triaged</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
  <script>
  console.log("initialised")

  let MDCDataTable = mdc.dataTable.MDCDataTable;

  let el = document.getElementById("table1");
  let dataTable = new MDCDataTable(el);
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type  `td:nth-of-type(2) {display;none;}`

Comment: thanks @MisterJojo this got me onto the right path. I was looking for something specific from Material but I realise I just use generic css such as `.mdc-data-table__cell{height:32px}` or `.mdc-data-table__cell,.mdc-data-table__header-cell{padding-right:4px;padding-left:4px}`